# "Крещеная" — сколько Н?

Tags: орфография

Скажите, пожалуйста, по какому правилу в слове "крещеная" пишется одно Н?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~3. Причастия не на -ованный (-ёванный, -еванный) глаголов несовершенного вида (они образуются Только от бесприставочных глаголов) и соотносительные с ними прилагательные пишутся по-разному: причастия с нн, прилагательные — с одним н, напр.: гружённые дровами повозки, жаренная на масле рыба, писанная маслом картина, стриженные парикмахером волосы и коротко стриженные волосы, крашенные зелёной краской скамейки, давно не метённый пол, ещё не белённые стены, уже не раз считанные деньги, деланное много раз предложение; но: гружёная баржа, жареная рыба, писаная красавица, стриженые волосы, крашеные скамейки, метёный пол, белёные стены, считаные минуты, деланое равнодушие; аналогично вязанный и вязаный, глаженный и глаженый, плетённый и плетёный, чищенный и чищеный; так же пишутся: жёванный и жёваный, клёванный и клёваный, кованный и кованый.

По этому правилу пишутся формы двувидовых глаголов контузить, крестить и ранить. Ср.: контуженный в голову боец, тяжело раненный солдат, раненный в ногу солдат, только что крещённый младенец, но: контуженый командир, раненый солдат, крещёный ребёнок.

(Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации под. ред Лопатина. §  98 п. 3)

Answer (score 0):

Добавить нечего. Всё точно расписано.

Comment: Так это цитата из Лопатина.  )